# how to put subcategory precisely under the category in drop-down list by asp.net core mvc?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I could connect every subcategory with the category by recursion way, and right everything is correct. But I want to put subcategory precisely under the category. But right now the user can't understand which subcategory is related to other categories.in fact I want to specify each subcategory for its category that's all.if you have any idea,I would know about that.this style I want to use in drop down list (I mean text along with dash).
this is my drop down doesn't any dash character and of course each subcategory  has to be under it's category. exactly like second picture.
[image]

[image]

```
News

-Sport News

--Soccer News

--- Beach Soccer News

-Political News
```

---

```
public class Category
    {

        public Category()
        {
            Categories = new List<Category>();
        }

        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public int? ParenetCategoryID { get; set; }
        public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    }
```

---

```
    public IActionResult ShowCategory()
    {
        var categories = _context.Categories
            .Where(c => c.ParenetCategoryID == null)
            .Select(c => new Category { CategoryID = c.CategoryID, CategoryName = c.CategoryName }).ToList();
        foreach (var item in categories)
        {
            _repository.ExtractSubCategories(item);
        }

        return View(categories);
    }
```

---

```
 private void ExtractSubCategories(Category category)
        {

            var subcategories = _context.Categories
                .Where(c => c.ParenetCategoryID == category.CategoryID)
                .Select(c => new Category
                {
                    CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                    CategoryName = c.CategoryName
                }).ToList();


            foreach (var item in subcategories)
            {

                ExtractSubCategories(item);
                category.Categories.Add(item);

            }

        }
```

---

```
    public IActionResult CreateCategory()
    {

        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(_context.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult CreateCategory(Category category)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            var newCat = new Category
            {
                ParenetCategoryID = category.CategoryID,
                CategoryName = category.CategoryName
            };
            _context.Categories.AddAsync(newCat);
            _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("ShowCategory");
        }

    }
```

---

```
@model CategoryProject2.Models.Category
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateCategory";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Admin.cshtml";
}

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header bg-light">
            Category DropDown
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form asp-action="CreateCategory" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label"></label>

                    <select class="select2 js-states form-control" asp-for="CategoryID" asp-items="@ViewBag.CategoryID">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" asp-for="CategoryName"></label>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="CategoryName" class="form-control"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="CategoryName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create" />

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want exactly? it is not clear to me (and i wager others)... is this a CSS/visual question?

Comment: @aequalsb,I've added a picture,I need a exactly like that.it's not about CSS.

Comment: Can you include the razor syntax code for this.

Comment: @Llazar,I've added view code . and of course I've added status of my drop-down list.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called a *preorder traversal*. It's pretty easy to implement recursively:

```cs
public static List<string> PreorderCategories(string prefix,
                                       List<Category> categories, int? parentID) 
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    var children = categories.Where(c => c.ParentCategoryID == parentID);       
    foreach (var category in children) {
        result.Add(prefix + category.CategoryName);
        result.AddRange(PreorderCategories(prefix + "- ", categories, category.CategoryID));
    }
    return result;          
}
```

What this code does is for each child of a node it first adds the child to the result (this is what makes it ***pre***order) and directly after it recursively adds all the child's children. At each level it adds a dash (and space) to the prefix so that the results reflect the tree depth.

To start this off you create another function to call this one with the root[s] of your tree[s].

```cs
public static List<string> PreorderCategories() 
{
    return PreorderCategories("", _context.Categories, null);
}
```

You may need to tweak the return types to integrate this with your UI.

Here's a demo of a mocked version on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kwUMVm)